# How many verbs can be used with 到?

Tags: grammar, verbs

I see  到 used with some verbs describing a result, I am wondering if there are a specific number of verbs in the structure V+(de)dao到. Is there an exhaustive number of verbs that can be used with V+ 到? Or is it just a limited number of verbs and if yes, where can I find them?

Comment: You need to provide a few examples for "v + 到" describing a result to differentiate the usual case that it means the action described by the verb is/has completed.

Answer (score 1):

Any verb that can be deemed **successful** or takes an **object** can use 到

Let's randomly pick a few unrelated verbs and see which of them can or cannot use 到

碰、看、打、走、學、想、哭、笑

碰到 (O) touch - *you can attempt to touch but not actually succeed, 到 indicates it is touched successfully*

看到 (O) see - *you can attempt to see but not actually succeed, 到 indicates it is seen successfully*

打到 (O) hit - *you can attempt to hit but not actually succeed, 到 indicates it is hit successfully*

走到 (O) walk/ go -  "走到 somewhere", and this "somewhere" is the object

學到 (O) learn *you can attempt to learn but not actually succeed, 到 indicates it is learned successfully*

想到 (O) think - "想到 something", and this "something" is the object

哭到 (X) cry - *you don't have to try to cry, so it can't be deemed successful, and 哭 doesn't take an object*

笑到 (X) laugh - *you don't have to try to laugh, so it can't be deemed successful, and 笑 doesn't take an object*

Comment: also: Verb+到+Adj doing something to some extent: 哭到眼肿，笑到窒息

Answer (score 1):

The interpretation of "success" happens only when the process is associated with a target in the first place. For example:

- 他去了校长办公室三次，昨天终于见到校长。
- 今天我很早就去市场，所以买到新鲜的鲫鱼。
- 我找到钥匙了，原来在抽屉里。

When we delimit a target P, we also envisage the non P (out of the target). The idea of success comes from hitting P and not non P.

If the process is not associated with a predefined target, we don't have the interpretation of "success". Instead, we have a kind of "it so happened that...". For example:

- 我昨天去商场买东西，看到我们的校长。
- 她真幸运，在沙滩散步时找到一只漂亮的贝壳。

In the classic situation of "Pick a card, any card", one uses 到 with any card he just happens to have picked:

- 我抽到黑桃2。
- 我抽到红心A。
- 我抽到... etc.

It is like calling what you have hit the target only after shooting.

Comment: Sorry to differ. I think "v+ 到" in all example sentences simply implies the actions are complete. The sense of "successfully happens" is indicated by the modifiers  "终于", "所以", and 原来.